# How to do mongo db aggregation join operation in php?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, php-mongodb

I have three collections in mongodb like

```
    employeeTitleTbl contains 

    {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a7c2027d2ccda04d0006070"),
    "EmployeeTitleName": "Librarian",
    "EmployeeTitleCode": "ji8766",
   ..
    }

 DepartmentsTbl contains

  {
   "_id": ObjectId("5a817402d2ccda13240015a5"),
   "DepartmentCode": "149",
   "DepartmentName": "Biology",
  ..
 }

 EmployeesTbl contains 

  {
   "_id": ObjectId("5a81957bd2ccda13240015a8"),
    "EmployeeNumber": "25789998",
   "JobTitle": ObjectId("5a7c2008d2ccda04d000606f"),
   "Department": ObjectId("5a8173e6d2ccda13240015a4"),
       ...
  }
```

I am very new to mongodb and also driver has also updated 3.6, so it is very difficult to find the latest method of aggregation in php.  So I was tweaking the below code for adding department and employee title actual values like "EmployeeTitleName" and "DepartmentName" in EmployeesTbl.

```
  public function fetchAll()
{         
        $pipeline = array(
                            array(
                                '$lookup' => array(
                                'from' => 'DepartmentsTbl',
                                'localField' => 'Department',
                                'foreignField' => '_id',
                                'as' => 'DepartmentDetails'
                                      )
                                  ),

                                array(
                                '$lookup' => array(
                                'from' => 'employeeTitleTbl',
                                'localField' => 'JobTitle',
                                'foreignField' => '_id',
                                'as' => 'JobTitleDetails'
                                      )
                                  ),
                         );

                 try
                 {                    

                    $cursor = $this->db->EmployeesTbl->aggregate($pipeline);

                 }

                 catch(Exception $e){

                 }

    return $cursor->toArray();
}
```

Please help me in latest method!!!

The output is like

array(2) { [0]=> object(MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument)#29 (1) { ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=> array(25) { ["_id"]=> object(MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId)#10 (1) { ["oid"]=> string(24) "5a8176c0d2ccda13240015a6" } ["EmployeeNumber"]=> string(8) "25799989"....
...........
["DepartmentDetails"]=> object(MongoDB\Model\BSONArray)#27 (1) { ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=> array(0) { } } ["JobTitleDetails"]=> object(MongoDB\Model\BSONArray)#28 (1) { ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=> array(0) { } } } } [1]=.........

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. I guess the problem is that `*Details` fields are always empty. Both `localField` and `foreignField` should be of the same type. In your example the former is a string, the later is "ObjectId". They never match. As a side note, you probably want to `return $cursor->toArray();` within the `try` block, or return something from the `catch` one.

Comment: u r absolutely right.. the data type doesnot match here... can u please tell me if both will be stored as object... will the above query work or is there some other method for doing so...

Comment: The id's should match. They don't in the example. Are you sure they do in the actual database?

Comment: u r right sir... thanks for solving my problem...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use $lookup to join 2 or more tables for example..

```
 db.employeeTitle.aggregate([{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'employees',
    localField: 'EmployeeTitleName',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'employeeData'
  }
 },
 { $unwind: '$employeeData' },
 {
   $project: { profile: '$employeeData' }     
 }    
])
```

It joins two tables employeeTitle and employees and give you full information about employees.